# Hide page action popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to automatically hide the popup of my page action when the user pressed a button on it. As I read at the forums of Chromium this was not possible in 2011 - anybody knows if it is possible and if yes how to accomplish this?

Greetings
Florian

Update:
Ok, it was really simple. It is just `window.close()` as the popup is actually the window of the embedded page. Some guy posted a comment taking me to this solution - but out of some reason he deleted his comment...

Comment: Either convert your findings into an answer, or delete the question, depending on whether you find this useful for StackOverflow - don't leave this question open.

Comment: Sorry, that was me in the comment. I wrote it and then I realized that you were talking about a page action and not a browser action, so I decided to check first if that worked, because I never used a page action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can simply call `window.close()` on the click handler for your button.

Comment: How do you add a click handler on the button? (Sorry I'm a rookie)